# BLE interference from DC motors

Tags: wireless, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, remote-control, raspberry-pi-pico

#### The problem:

I am making a remote control car. The car is being run with a Raspberry Pi Pico W. The power source is a 11.1 V Li-po. The power to the Pico is being stepped down with a 5 V regulator. I have four 6-12 V Brushed DC motors powered directly off the 11.1 V from the battery.

The car is controlled via Bluetooth Low Energy via the Pico W and a smartphone app. I am experiencing a substantial decrease in the Bluetooth range when the motors are running (about 10-15 ft. max). This causes a sudden disconnect. If I disconnect the motors, I can communicate with the car over a range of 40+ ft. I am using 24 AWG wire for all the wiring.

#### Current layout:

[image: Four motors arranged in a rectangle, with the Pico in the center]
[image: Wiring Diagram]

#### Diagnostic steps taken:

- Drive motors at a lower voltage

  - With a 5 V regulator on the motors, the range was improved, but still limited (the motors are also too slow at this voltage).
- Moved the Pico

  - The further I moved the Pico away from the motors, the better it got. I had to move it almost a foot away for the range to be unaffected. This is less than ideal because the car is fairly small.
- I confirmed that the Pico is not losing power, and it is purely losing Bluetooth signal.

#### Question:

Is there a way to reduce the Bluetooth interference caused by the motors while still having the Pico fairly close?

#### Notes:

- I need all four motors as it is using Mecanum wheels
- I need the Pico W, as it has some more advanced features than just a "normal car"

Comment: How well did you pay attention to ground returns in your wiring? Could you provide the actual wiring diagram? What about shielding of motor feeds? Are you using brushed motors?

Comment: I updated the post with a diagram. Yes the motors are brushed (here is the link to the exact motors https://www.amazon.com/Antrader-Motor-Shaft-Arduino-Smart/dp/B07DDC3ZBK/?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_w=9zsZG&content-id=amzn1.sym.d0ebfbb2-6761-494f-8e2f-95743b37c35c%3Aamzn1.symc.50e00d6c-ec8b-42ef-bb15-298531ab4497&pf_rd_p=d0ebfbb2-6761-494f-8e2f-95743b37c35c&pf_rd_r=FCXX4DJ6KSCV9DT0TQ28&pd_rd_wg=hgRsp&pd_rd_r=73bc3d00-9611-4dc5-9dc1-8a03f65ebc9b&ref_=pd_gw_ci_mcx_mr_hp_atf_m

Comment: This is a schematic diagram, I was asking to show your actual wiring diagram, in particular how do you connect ground wires, is there a common stretch of wire that might experience "ground bounce" when motors are operating. Also, it is very common to put LC filters on each motor, to filter parasitic emission from brushes. What kind of filters do you use? DO you have the motor's body grounded via a separate shield wire? What kind of filtering do you have before the 5V regulator, and after it?

Comment: Yes there’s is one common stretch of ground that everything is connected to (not familiar with the concept of “ground bouncing”).I do not have any sort of LC filters on the motors (I would love some suggestions of what to use in this particular case. Some sort of Ceramic Capacitor?). I do not have the motors ground via a separate shielding wire (how would I do this). I do not have any filtering before or after the 5V regulator

Comment: What's your wiring, decoupling and flyback situation around the motor drivers? Also, is there any capacitor straight across the motor terminals?

Comment: @thrandale Brushed DC motors, running, completely surrounding a BLE in a thin can. I'd love to see the scope results using a directional antenna pointing at it while running the motors and connected through a carefully designed and constructed RF amplifier tuned for BLE band vs without the motors running. That may give some idea what the BLE is dealing with. (Even with ceramic caps directly across the motors.)

Comment: @thrandale Even with ceramic caps, brushed DC motors should be placed ***as far away from sensitive circuits as possible*** and even after that you may need additional metal enclosures. And even then you may still have troubles. You are talking about the Low Energy version, after all. I'm not surprised, I guess.

Comment: What voltage rating and capacitance should I use for the ceramic caps across the motors? Will standard Bluetooth be less affected than BLE?

Comment: @thrandale The motor manufacturer would be the place to go for recommendations for capacitors (or other methods) of reducing EMI. We used to be able to get and use mumetal screens, as well, for DC brushed motors. No idea if that's available anymore or if the casing of motors today are less needy for something like that than once was. Standard Bluetooth will probably be better than BLE (almost sure it will be -- but I'm ignorant of the details so I don't really know.)